# Using SoundManager2 to create a non downloadable playlist

Tags: google-app-engine, audio, soundcloud, google-cloud-storage, soundmanager2

Currently I am trying to develop a Music streaming service: using SoundManager2 for streaming. I am using Google App engine to do the same. Music files are stored in Google Cloud Storage Buckets. 
After completion of each song I would do an ajax query to fetch the url of the next playable song.

But while doing so I expose the direct URL to the .mp3 file and I am able to download the same thorough the URL (with a little help from Chrome Developers Tool).

**How can we stop the song from getting downloaded or do some thing like SoundCloud where the URL is not getting identified in Developers tool?**